# Tensorflow dataset produced in Python has different readings in Tensorflow Java API (Label Image)

Tags: java, python, image, tensorflow, classification

Background: I am new to Tensorflow and AI and wish to try out Tensorflow in a Java based environment. Found Tensorflow has a Java API and tried it out but results don't seem to be similar to my Python implementations. I used Maven for my Java implementation.

I had retrained a dataset using Tensorflow in Python by following the [Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) tutorial.

In a Python based Tensorflow environment the dataset outputs values which are more or less correct. For example, if I have an image of a car and my classification options are car, bug,or building; it would output car.

But in my Java equivalent which I tried using the Tensorflow Java API and [Image label demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java); the datasets I produced earlier are readable but the outputs are completely different from the Python implementation. Unlike the Python example, if I throw a car it would output it as a bug or building.

I had tried the output data on several different machines with processors and gpus from different generations to see if it would affect the output; but it appears to be exclusive with the language/API.

1. Any ideas as to why the two implementations using the same dataset
   produce completely different outputs?
2. And is there any way I could get my Java version to output similar
   results to my Python example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently the graph construction in the "tensorflow for poets" and java "label image" feature different dimensions when plotting/constructing the graph hence the skewed results I received. The difference in dimensions led to completely different constructed results.

1. Output is different due to graph mapping issue pertaining to image itself. The tutorial dimensions and java sample dimensions were different.
2. Readjust dimensions to fit. Both  require a common or similar dimension reading for graph reconstruction.